# Не применяются стили в медиа запросах, при работе с SASS

Tags: sass

```css
@import "vars"

/*==========  Desktop First  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) 
    
    .hamburger
        position: absolute
        right: 10px
    
    .media-links
        position: absolute
        right: 30px
        margin: 10px

    
    


/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) 
        .top-line
            background: #fff
```

Попытаюсь описать проблему. Работаю с препроцесотром SASS второй раз, первый раз когда работал с этим припроцессором всё работало, все стили применялись. Но вот сейчас когда хочу применить стиль на медиа запросе 
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px)

он тупо не применяется.

И ещё 
на медиа запросе в 1200px почему-то выдаёт такую вот ошибку.

expected "{", was ";"
        on line 6 of app/sass/_media.sass

Но когда оборачиваю  стили в фигурные скобки , всё нормально работает, хотя так не должно быть с SASS там эти скобки не нужны.

Не могу понять в чём проблемма

Консоль

Comment: код, в котором возникает ошибка?

Comment: @NeedHate Добавил

Comment: в предоставленном коде ошибок нет, он нормально у меня компилируется.

Comment: @NeedHate Так и я думаю что должно и у меня компилить, НО вот что выдаёт консоль [01:09:32] gulp-autoprefixer:
  autoprefixer: C:\Users\anton\Desktop\site\app\sass\main.min.css:6277:5: Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like `to left` instead of `right`.
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (main.min.css)
[01:09:32] Finished 'sass' after 4

Comment: @NeedHate А в чём может ещё быть проблема, кроме кода?

Comment: Почему вы решили что у вас ошибка в коде выше, а не в градиенте о котором вам говорит консоль?

Comment: @E_K Да скорее всего, я хотел в стилях изменить градиент, с  background: linear-gradient(left, #fff 0%, #fff 75.5%, #101010 30%, #101010 100%); Я хотел заменить в медиа запросах на bgc: #fff, я так понимаю так нельзя

Comment: @BraFik, у вас ошибка в градиенте. вместо `left` используйте `to left`.

Comment: @E_K Да спасибо вы были правы у меня в самом градиенте была ошибка. Хотел бы ещё поинтересоватся, почему может не перезначатся градиент в медиа запросе.?

Comment: @BraFik, может спецефичность селекторов, ошибка в коде. Сложно сказать не видя код